# What is a set theoretic product of groups?

Tags: group-theory

[image]

I'm doing this exercise from Gorodentsev's Algebra 1. But I don't understand the notation of operation " componentwize composition".

It's not the external direct product.

How do I find $g_x \  h_x $. Is $G_x \subset G$?`

Comment: Maybe it's easier to grasp for finite $X$, especially $X:=\{1,2\}$. Then $\prod_{x\in X}G_x=G_1\times G_2$, and componentwise composition means $(g_1,g_2)\cdot(h_1,h_2):=(g_1\cdot h_1,g_2\cdot h_2)$ (writing the group operation as $\cdot$).

Comment: ( . ) is the operation on both groups ?

Comment: If G=D4 and H=Z2 for example . What is G x H ?? It's Cartesian product pairs ?

Comment: Yes, I was writing all group operations as $\cdot$ for convenience. Your example has too many elements for a comment, so I'm going with the easier example $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_3$. Its elements are $(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2)$, and for instance $(1,1)+(0,2):=(1+0,1+2)=(1,0)$. The first component follows the rules of $\mathbb Z_2$, the second component follows the rules of $\mathbb Z_3$.

Comment: So yes, the *set* containing the elements of the product $G\times H$ is just the cartesian product $G\times H$ (as the notation already implies). And the composition rule says to just compose the entries of the first component according to the composition rules of $G$, and the entries of the second component according to the rules of $H$.

Comment: ok . I got you . This is called the external direct prdoduct with a ( plus sign in a circle ) as i know . I thought there's a new operation between D4 x Z2  .
Thanks !

Comment: The plus sign is something different, though the difference is only visible when we do infinite sums/products. The sum only allows a finite number of entries to be different from the neutral element. The product allows all of them to be different from the neutral element. As mentioned, this makes no difference for finite products/sums, but you're dealing with arbitrary products, so it's important to make the distinction.